# The namespace attribute has been set but is empty

Tags: .net, msbuild, wix, msdn, wix3.8

I have written an inline msbuild task that won't compile. The error reads "The 'Namespace' attribute has been set but is empty. If the 'Namespace' attribute is set it must not be empty." **Note: This is a Wix Installer Project.** Here is my code:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
         <ConnectionString Condition=" '$(ConnectionString)' == ''">Server=???;Database=???;Integrated Security=True;</ConnectionString>
         <SqlCommand Condition=" '$(SqlCommand)' == '' ">???</SqlCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <UsingTask 
        TaskName="ExecuteScalar" 
        TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory"
        AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
            <ParameterGroup>
                <ConnectionString ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
                <CommandText ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
                <Result ParameterType="System.String" Output="true" />
            </ParameterGroup>
        <Task>
            <Reference Include="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll" />      
            <Using Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" />
            <Using Namepsace="System.Data.Sql" />
            <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs"><![CDATA[
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
                {

                  conn.Open();

                  using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText, conn))
                  {
                    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;             

                    Result = cmd.ExecuteScalar() as string;
                  }}]]>
             </Code>
        </Task>
    </UsingTask>

    <Target Name="MyTarget">   
        <ExecuteScalar ConnectionString="$(ConnectionString)"
                   CommandText="$(SqlCommand)">
            <Output TaskParameter="Result" PropertyName="MyProperty" />
        </ExecuteScalar>
    </Target>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <BuildDependsOn>
            BeforeBuild;
            CoreBuild;
            AfterBuild
        </BuildDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="$(BuildDependsOn)" />

    <PropertyGroup>
         <BuildDependsOn>
            MyTarget;
            $(BuildDependsOn)
         </BuildDependsOn>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

I cannot find anything when I search on this error. I appreciate any help.

I have been referencing:

- [MSDN UsingTask Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t41tzex2.aspx)
- [MSDN Walkthrough: Creating an Inline Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723643.aspx)
- [Visual Studio MSBuild Inline Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd722601%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo here:

```
<Using Namepsace="System.Data.Sql" />
```

Change `Namepsace` to `Namespace`

Comment: You rock and now I feel like a dork. Thank you much!